# Ubuntu 14.04 with acer timelinex 5830TG

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nvidia, bumblebee, acer

This is about using ubuntu on a specific machine. I have been using ubuntu on an acer timelinex 5830TG with 8 gb ram and 750gb HD with 1 gb Nvidia G540M. However I haven't been able to use the graphic drivers properly.
I tried nvidia-current and other versions like 331 etc , I also tried using bumblebee. But none of these were using my hardware effectively.
This results in heavy decrease of battery like of 6+ hrs to around 2.5 hours.Moreover the system seems to hang very frequently.

My question is whether anyone has been able to use ubuntu with full support of the Nvidia card and if someone specifically has been able to exploit the battery backup with ubuntu for this laptop.

Additionally I wanted to know if its time to move past ubuntu and try other flavours of Linux. Would any other Linux use my laptop hardware (more)effectively?